# Iframe contact form dosen't send parent windows link

Tags: php, javascript

here is my site  http://www.atc-center.com. i have an inquiry form embed in  you can see at product page click at any product and find " Inquiry " in red.
i want to get the current url of page ( for product details). i tried many things but i can't get the url or product title. i tried some java script commands.
 here is code :

```
    <input type='hidden' name='purl' id='purl' 

   value='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>' /><br/>
```

and a  java script code at the end of form:

```
parent.document.getElementById('purl'). $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try use - `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` and check this link for details - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php